# Pequena duvida sobre Buttons

Tags: css

Bom dia gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de tirar esta linha azul a volta da imagem, a imagem e um botão

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia elaborar um [mcve] e adicioná-lo na pergunta, por favor?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [CSS - Como remover linhas em volta do botão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/273241/css-como-remover-linhas-em-volta-do-bot%c3%a3o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta tirar o Outline da elemento `button` assim:

```
button:focus, button:active {
    outline: none;
}
```

Mas vc não deveria fazer isso, até por uma questão de Acessibilidade... http://www.outlinenone.com/

Pensen que vc pode tratar o `outline` com css para ele ter um efeito mais legal em vez de c remove-lo. Aqui na documentação da Mozilla vc pode ver alguns exemplos práticos de como estilizar o `outline` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline

Exemplos de estilização do `outline`: (repare que mesmo o elemento sendo um P eu posso colocar o `outline` nele como uma borda só que sem interferir no *box-size* )

```css
p.dotted {outline-style: dotted; outline-color:red; outline-width: 5px;}
p.dashed {outline-style: dashed; outline-color:blue ; outline-width: 3px;}
p.solid {outline-style: solid; outline-color:green; outline-width: 3px;}
p.double {outline: 2px double gold;}
```

```html
<p class="dotted">A dotted outline</p>
<p class="dashed">A dashed outline</p>
<p class="solid">A solid outline</p>
<p class="double">A double outline</p>
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, muito agradecido